# How can I replace itertools.product without itertools?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, numba

So I am Currently working on a python script. Unfortunaly two modules don't work with one another. However I need one of them desperately ( numba ) and the other one (itertools) i feel like could be replaced easier.

I just need some way to turn an input like (3) into something that spits out all combinations of ascii letters within that length ( so in this case from a - aa - ab - ba - ... - ZZZ). Doesn't have to be precisely the input numbers equal the string length, but I need to perform a function on each String so I need them seperately.

I tried nested for loops but I've never gotten to the result I wanted.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify why you can not use `itertools.product` here? Because you are using `numba` for something else?

Comment: I want to use numba's jit with cudatoolkit to have the code either run on gpu or at least be ran on cpu but optimized. Unfortunately, there is no numba support for the itertools module yet and the code keeps erroring if both are in the code.

Comment: Please provide example data and the itertools code that you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the itertools code is in the documentation. They display equivalent or similar recipes too. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools Here:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Now that you have product without using itertools. You can

```
import string 
product(string.ascii_letters,list(string.ascii_letters)+[''],list(string.ascii_letters)+[''])
```